# No module named pycurl on mac terminal

Tags: python, macos, pycurl

When I start .py file I got this error? Why?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/omercancelikler/webstagram.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pycurl
ImportError: No module named pycurl
```

Comment: Have you installed `pycurl`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve ImportError "No module named pycurl"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958563/how-to-resolve-importerror-no-module-named-pycurl)