# Python throws an error even though pycurl is installed

Tags: python

I see when pycurl is installed but when I run a script which has pycurl it throws the error `ImportError: No module named pycurl`

pycurl installed

```
 users-iMac:clone_radar user$ sudo pip install pycurl
    The directory '/Users/user/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
    The directory '/Users/user/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
    Requirement already satisfied: pycurl in /Users/user/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
```

Error:-

```
users-iMac:clone_radar user$ python ./cloneradar.py username 4364_test radar.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cloneradar.py", line 7, in <module>
    from RadarWS import RadarWS
  File "/Users/user/Documents/cloning_radar/com/clone_radar/RadarWS.py", line 28, in <module>
    import pycurl
ImportError: No module named pycurl
```

if I try to install without sudo I get the error

```
Command "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/fh/1g80t0p942bf8_pnjjl8r21m0000gn/T/pip-build-QmeyZh/pycurl/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/fh/1g80t0p942bf8_pnjjl8r21m0000gn/T/pip-4p7wF2-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/fh/1g80t0p942bf8_pnjjl8r21m0000gn/T/pip-build-QmeyZh/pycurl
```

Comment: Did you try the suggested solutions on this SO question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958563/how-to-resolve-importerror-no-module-named-pycurl

Comment: Can you try running this from that script: `import sys; print sys.path`. Does it contain `/User/user/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages`?

Comment: You installed the package with `sudo`. Probably your web application has no access to the superuser's library.

Comment: @Magnus - I tried what you suggested ,I still get the same error

Comment: @pushkin - it has `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`

Comment: @masterfloda - I updated the question with the error I get if I try to install without sudo

Comment: @user3682248 Ok, so it looks like it's looking in a different directory. It's possible that `sudo` installs stuff in a different directory. Your `pycurl` is in `/Users/user/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages`, but `import` is looking in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`. This shouldn't go into production, but as a quick workaround, you can do `sys.path.append('/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages')`. Long-term, we'll need to figure out why it got installed to a different place.

Comment: @pushkin - is there a way to force pip to install in the specific directory it is looking for?

Comment: I recommend using a virtual environment: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/

Comment: @user3682248 [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980798/where-does-pip-install-its-packages) may help. You might try installing using `easy_install` also