# Python3 properly install PyCurl

Tags: python-3.x, pycurl

I'm trying to install `pycurl` on my `ubuntu 16.04 LTS`, the module looks installed but it gives me "No module named pycurl" when I try to import it from python.
my python3 version is `3.7.8`

`pip3 freeze |grep pycurl` tells me that version 7.43 is installed`pycurl==7.43.0`

I already run successfully :

```
apt-get update
apt-get install python3-pycurl
```

`python3 -m pip install pycurl` gives me :

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pycurl in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (7.43.0)
```

and `python3 -m easy_install pycurl` returns :

```
WARNING: The easy_install command is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Searching for pycurl
Best match: pycurl 7.43.0
Adding pycurl 7.43.0 to easy-install.pth file

Using /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Processing dependencies for pycurl
Finished processing dependencies for pycurl
```

after all of these I get this when I try to import the module :

```
>>> import pycurl
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycurl'
```

Any idea ?

#update

when I try `pip3 -v install pycurl --upgrade` I get this error

```
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages/pip/_internal/utils/subprocess.py", line 242, in 
call_subprocess
raise InstallationError(exc_msg)
pip._internal.exceptions.InstallationError: Command errored out with 
exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, 
tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install- 
jrmswlpf/pycurl/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install- 
jrmswlpf/pycurl/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' 
install --record /tmp/pip-record-0mjigz74/install-record.txt --single- 
version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install- 
headers 
/home/user/.local/include/python3.7m/pycurl Check the logs for full 
command output.
Removed build tracker: '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-w67dg62p'
```

#update 2 :
I run those commands : `sudo apt-get purge python3-pycurl` then `pip3 freeze|grep pycurl` returns nothing => pycurl is uninstalled

then, I run  `pip3 install pycurl`

```
pip3 install pycurl
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not 
writeable
Collecting pycurl
Using cached pycurl-7.43.0.5.tar.gz (216 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pycurl
Building wheel for pycurl (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; 
sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-umytzbub/pycurl/setup.py'"'"'; 
__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install- 
umytzbub/pycurl/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-31uhzig0
   cwd: /tmp/pip-install-umytzbub/pycurl/
Complete output (18 lines):
Using curl-config (libcurl 7.47.0)
Using SSL library: GnuTLS
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/curl
copying python/curl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/curl
running build_ext
building 'pycurl' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare - 
DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat - 
Werror=format-security -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat - 
Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC - 
DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.5" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_GNUTLS=1 - 
DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/docstrings.c -o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/docstrings.o
In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:0:
src/pycurl.h:5:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycurl
Running setup.py clean for pycurl
Failed to build pycurl
DEPRECATION: Could not build wheels for pycurl which do not use PEP 
517. pip will fall back to legacy 'setup.py install' for these. pip 
21.0 will remove support for this functionality. A possible 
replacement is to fix the wheel build issue reported above. You can 
find discussion regarding this at 
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8368.
Installing collected packages: pycurl
Running setup.py install for pycurl ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; 
sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-umytzbub/pycurl/setup.py'"'"'; 
__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install- 
umytzbub/pycurl/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', 
open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 
'"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-62fg7a92/install- 
record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= -- 
compile --install-headers 
/home/user/.local/include/python3.7m/pycurl
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-umytzbub/pycurl/
Complete output (18 lines):
Using curl-config (libcurl 7.47.0)
Using SSL library: GnuTLS
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/curl
copying python/curl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/curl
running build_ext
building 'pycurl' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare - 
DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat - 
Werror=format-security -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat - 
Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC - 
DPYCURL_VERSION="7.43.0.5" -DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -DHAVE_CURL_GNUTLS=1 - 
DHAVE_CURL_SSL=1 -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c src/docstrings.c -o 
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/src/docstrings.o
In file included from src/docstrings.c:4:0:
src/pycurl.h:5:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u - 
c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip- 
install-umytzbub/pycurl/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip- 
install-umytzbub/pycurl/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, 
'"'"'open'"'"', open) 
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', 
'"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 
'"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-62fg7a92/install- 
record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= -- 
compile --install-headers 
/home/user/.local/include/python3.7m/pycurl Check the logs for full 
command output.
```

Comment: Please try this answer URL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38072164/1489444 and let me know what is the response.

Comment: @ViswanathPolaki what do you mean ? the install with pip ? I've already tried as shown in the question, but doesn't work. pydocusign gives me version 2.2

Comment: Use python3 instead of python when you are testing.

Comment: hi @D.SM, what do you mean ? I'm always using python3

Comment: Okay. Delete both of the pycurl installations you added, then pick whether you want to use apt or pip, install pycurl one time, update question with results.

Comment: hi @D.SM, just did what you suggested. I updated the question (update 2). thanks for your help

Comment: Now you can follow official pycurl installation instructions where they talk about dev packages.

Answer (score 5):

I finally fixed this error by installing `libpython3.7-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install libpython3.7-dev
```

Comment: And on Windows ?